# How to transform a float 50.0 into an int 50 in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, int

i need a function like this:

```
>>> a = 5.0
>>> a = integer(a)
>>> a
>>> 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it an int:

```
int(r)
```

And don't call the variable the same name as the module, otherwise you can't access the module anymore. That's why I used `r` instead.

That said, your comparison should work anyway, because Python is smart:

```
>>> 5.0 == 5
True
```

Finally, since you apparently want a multiple of 10 from 0 to 90, I'd just do this:

```
int(random.random() * 10) * 10
```

Comment: @LiamGiannini What exactly?

Comment: @LiamGiannini How does it not work? What is the problem? I can't read your mind.

Answer (score 2):

`>>> int(50.0)

50`

Use int(expression) to convert a value to int.

Comment: I've just checked and this works for me. Anyway, I have active python 2.7.9(although I do not think they have modified this behavior).

Comment: int(round(random.randrange(0, 100)/10)*10) returns an int for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `int` function

e.g

```
x=50.0
x=int(x)
```